# Add class based on menu item click

Tags: javascript, css

If i click left of active menu item eg:1,2 menu item i want to add "uk-animation-slide-left-small" class else add "uk-animation-slide-right-small" class if i click right of active menu item eg:4,5 menu item. Without jquery.

```html
<script src="https://getuikit.com/assets/uikit/dist/js/uikit.js"></script>
<link href="https://getuikit.com/assets/uikit/dist/css/uikit.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<ul class="uk-subnav uk-subnav-pill" uk-switcher="animation: uk-animation-slide-right-small">
    <li><a href="#">Item1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item2</a></li>
    <li class="uk-active"><a href="#">Main</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Item4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item5</a></li>
</ul>

<ul class="uk-switcher uk-margin">
    <li>Content1</li>
    <li>Content2</li>
    <li>Content3</li>
    <li>Content4</li>
    <li>Content5</li>
</ul>
```

> I want to recreate https://getuikit.com/v2/docs/switcher.html#switcher-animations -> Slide Horizontal effect

Comment: use the oncontextmenu event to every link. check if className equals uk-active then prevent the default. find the active uk-active in uk-switcher remove the class und attach it to a othernode

Comment: > `without jquery` - you should consider checking https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList